# A divisibility rule for 19

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Proof the following divisibility test for 19:

Add two times the last digit to the remaining leading truncated number. If the result is divisible by 19, then so was the first number.

More mathematically:

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Proof that $10a+b$ is divisible by 19 if $a+2b$ is divisible by 19.

My guess is that we can proof this using congruences.

Comment: I think you meant "if $\;10a+2b\;$ is divisible by $\;19\;$"

Comment: Sorry, you're only interested in two digit multiples of $19$?  But there are only $5$ of them....$\{19,38,57,76,95\}$ and it is easy to check that in each case $a+2b=19$.  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @DonAntonio No. See one of the answers.

Comment: @lulu Why two digits? Every natural number can be wrriten as $\;10a+b\;$ , with $\;a,b\in\Bbb Z\;$ . In fact, $\;b\;$ can be taken to simply be a digit and, in my opinion, it'd be way clearer had the OP written that.

Comment: @DonAntonio  Oh, I took $a,b$ to be the digits of the number.  So $10a+b$ equaled the original.  On rereading, your interpretation is certainly better.

Comment: @lulu $b$ is the last digit of a positive integer and $a$ is the "remaining leading truncated number". E.g., in $194$ we would get $b=4$, $a=19$.

Comment: @user236182 I can't see why the unique answer there is answers that. Besides, the OP's words are "add two times the last *digit* to **the remainded leading truncated number**..." If the number is $\;10a+b\;,\;\;b\;$ a digit, then $\;2b\;$ must be added to $\;10a\;$, **not** to $\;a\;$ ...or I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: @DonAntonio For contradiction, let your statement be true. If $19\mid 10a+2b$, then $19\mid 10a+b$. But then $19\mid (10a+2b)-(10a+b)=b$, so $b$ is divisible by $19$. If $b$ is taken as a one-digit number, then $b=0$. So it wouldn't be true for a number with a different last digit than $0$, contradiction.

Comment: @user236182 True, I fell into my own explanation contradiction...if $\;10a+b\;$ is a number, with $\;a\in\Bbb Z\,,\,\,b\;$ *a digit*, then it surely must be $\;a+2b\;$. Thanks.

Comment: By the [general divisibility test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2989299/242) in the linked dupe: 
$$ \color{#0a0}{19}\mid \color{#c00}{10}\,a+b \!\iff\! 19\mid a+\color{#c00}c\,b,\ \ {\rm for}\ \ \,  \color{#c00}{c\equiv  \dfrac{1}{10}}\equiv\dfrac{2}{20}\equiv\color{#c00}{\dfrac{2}{1}}\!\!\!\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}{19}}\qquad$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$10a+b$ is divisible by $19$ if and only if $20a+2b$ is divisible by $19$, of course $20a+2b\equiv a+2b\bmod 19$

Comment: How can the last step be justified?

Comment: $20-1=19{}{}{}{}$