# Prove The Divisibility rule of 19

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I'm a beginner in number theory, I was trying to prove the divisibility rule of 19, can someone help me to complete my proof

Let $n$ be $10a + b$ where b is the unit digit and 10a is the rest; 10 is coprime to 19,
$n \equiv 0 \pmod{19} \iff a+2b \equiv 0 \pmod {19} \iff x\cdot a + x\cdot 2b \equiv 0 \pmod{19} \iff 10a + b \equiv 0 \pmod{19}$
Where it holds that $10a + b - (x\cdot a + x\cdot 2b) = 19k \space or \\ 10a + b - (x\cdot a + x\cdot 2b) \equiv 0 \pmod{19}$

but I have a problem finding the $x$ multiplier.

I've visited [A divisibility rule for 19](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898380/a-divisibility-rule-for-19), Didn't quite understand what has been done there; and the important factor is that I want the approach I'm taking completed.

If my proof is completely meaningless etc, I'd appreciate a proof like it.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want $xa + xb$? Typically they go for $a + xb$, so you're adding x times the last digit to the rest of the number.

Comment: Maybe, I tried to take the approach used for 17, and 13, I'm like really beginner

Comment: Sure, can you write up the approach used for 17? That will help us tell if you make an error trying to generalize the approach.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Try $x=10$.  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898380/a-divisibility-rule-for-19).  And it's confusing to let $a$ be $10a+b$

Comment: @CalvinLin [Proof the divisibility rule of 17](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174175/proof-of-the-divisibility-rule-of-17)

Comment: (Apart from your $a$ doing double duty like Tanner pointed out) You see what I mean by "Typically they go for $a  + xb$?" In the link, they say that $17 \mid a - 5 b \Leftrightarrow 17 \mid 10a + b$.

Comment: I edited the question so it isn't 2 a's in use
You see the approach taken in the 17(as I understood) is that they're subtracting $x$ from $17k$ to get to $17j$ resulting in x also a multiply of 17
I tried to take the same approach
But I don't know what Should be $x$ resulting in a $19j$

Comment: As $2$ is the multiplicative inverse of $10$ modulo $19$, the result follows from [this more general result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1961065/11619). Not voting to close this as a duplicate yet, because A) I happened to answer that query and B) it is possible that's not the first incarnation on our site.

Comment: By the [general divisibility test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2989299/242) in the linked dupe: 
$$ \color{#0a0}{19}\mid \color{#c00}{10}\,a+b \!\iff\! 19\mid a+\color{#c00}c\,b,\ \ {\rm for}\ \ \,  \color{#c00}{c\equiv  \dfrac{1}{10}}\equiv\dfrac{2}{20}\equiv\color{#c00}{\dfrac{2}{1}}\!\!\!\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}{19}}\qquad$$ See the detailed proofs there (which are no simpler in this special case). $\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user [J. W. Tanner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/615567/j-w-tanner). The answer for $x$ is 10, Giving us this
$a+2b \equiv 0 \pmod {19} \iff 10a + 20b \equiv 0 \pmod{19} \iff 10a + b \equiv 0 \pmod{19} \iff n \equiv 0 \pmod{19}$
This is Because:
$10a + b - (10a + 20b) = -19b \equiv 0 \pmod{19} \iff x \equiv 0 \pmod{19}$

Comment: I think that after the second double implication, the expression should be $10a+20b$ (rather than $20a+20b$).

Comment: Oh, yes thanks i prob made a mistake while typing it

Comment: I think you don't want to begin your chain of implications with $n \equiv 0 \pmod{19}$ since that is what you are trying to prove. It's where the chain ends.

Comment: I think you meant $10a+b-(10a+20b)=\color{red}-19b$, but it's still $\equiv0\pmod{19}$; and the choice $x=10$ was rather obvious when you wrote $a+2b\dots\iff 10a\dots$ in the question

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).